# ADB doesn't see my Nexus 7 running on Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, adb, android-6.0-marshmallow, nexus-7

I am developing an Android application and testing with a Nexus 7 device which runs on Android 6.0.1.

The problem is that when I try to use this device to test ADB doesn't see it !
Here is my build.gradle file if you can help me :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sifast.gpstracking.client"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
}
```

Comment: What operation system do you use? What is the output of "adb devices" in your terminal?

Comment: Its hardware issue. not with your gradle.

Comment: try with every usb ports. some time usb issue arise due to malfuncton.

Comment: It was about activating Developer Mode guys, thank you anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Google USB Driver to connect to Nexus devices, see : http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Also you need to activate Developer Mode, by clicking multiple times on *Build number* under *About phone*

After you did this you can access *Developer options* there you can turn on *USB debugging* and when you connnect your device to the pc a dialog will pop up to allow this pc USB debugging.

If your device is connected successfully you should have a notification with *USB debugging connected*

Is that the case?